# Compilation error when comparing a string with a char in a Hangman project

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a hangman game:

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let mut isRunning: bool = true;

    'outer: loop {
        let w1 = vec!['m', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'y']; //the answer
        println!("Guess a Character");

        loop {
            let mut line = String::new(); //the guess

            let input = stdin().read_line(&mut line);
            let char_vec: Vec<char> = line.to_string().chars().collect();

            for x in 0..4 {
                if line == w1[x] {
                    println!("you guessed right? ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error when comparing the user input to the letters in the word:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::cmp::PartialEq<char>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:25
   |
17 |                 if line == w1[x] {
   |                         ^^ can't compare `std::string::String` with `char`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<char>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
```

Why this doesn't work as intended?

Comment: "this doesn't work as intended", alright, but what's not working then?

Comment: "hanging man simulation" for non english speaker please explain the behavior wanted and the problem you are facing to.

Comment: the program asks for a character > and the user inputs one > and then the program compares the guess to the word to see if there is a match with characters

Comment: @CharlesJonasson if your program does not compile, please edit the question to include the error and explain what you do not understand in the error message. If your program does compile, please edit your question to add a description of what exactly is the current behaviour and how it differs from the expected behaviour.

Comment: @CharlesJonasson [edit] your question to make it better would be much better than ask information in comment section. You should read [ask].

Comment: I've edited the question to include the error message that you'd see with the source code you have provided. A `String` cannot be compared to a `char`. So you need to find a way to turn your `String` into `char`s or your `char` into a `String` so they can be compared.

Comment: And it looks like you were already on your way to doing that when you created the `char_vec` variable. But then you don't use it! Comparing `char_vec[0]` instead of `line` will at least compile. I can't tell you if this is what you actually want your program to do though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the critical part of the error message:

```
can't compare `std::string::String` with `char`
```

The problem is that you're storing the user input as a `String`, but trying to compare it with a `char`. There are a couple of solutions. Perhaps the simplest is to use the first `char` from the user input `String`:

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    'outer: loop {
        let w1 = vec!['m', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'y']; //the answer
        println!("Guess a Character");

        loop {
            let mut line = String::new(); //the guess

            stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            if line.len() < 1 || line.len() > 1 {
                println!("Please guess a single char.");
            } else {
                let guess = line.chars().next().unwrap();
                let mut correct = false;
                for c in &w1 {
                    if guess == *c {
                        correct = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if correct {
                    println!("You guessd right!");
                } else {
                    println!("You guessed wrong...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String::len` returns the size in bytes, not in `chars`. So if I were to guess that your word starts with `é`, your function would tell me "Please guess a single char.".